# How do I open a `.pb` file? Ideally, how to import it into Meta Quest 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, oculus, matterport

I'm using Matterport's free scanning software for Android and it spits out 2 files called `2b7cb66c-4c9e-408d-88c5-90b8c0322c13_sweep_features.pb` and `2b7cb66c-4c9e-408d-88c5-90b8c0322c13_sweep_cloud.pb` (the important thing is that they're of the forms `[nums]_sweep_features.pb` and `[nums]_sweep_cloud.pb`).

:^)

###### How can I open `.pb` files?

.

=======================================================

=======================================================

###### My ultimate goal: the room in VR

I need to know how to open the file so I can walk around the rooms I scan in my Meta Quest 2 VR Headset.  Ideally, I'd get it working in Unity, but UnrealEngine would be fine too.  The most important thing is that I get the numerical and/or color information about the scanned room.  Besides `sweep_cloud.pb`, there is also a file called `sweep_features.pb`.

1. Maybe `.pb` is a Tensorflow format?  I say that because most of the `.pb` files I have found through Google for are [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers), many of which store Neural Network (Tensorflow) files, and "`feature`" is jargon in Neural Networks and Machine Learning more generally!
2. Another guess would be something like a `.obj` file, a numpy (`.npy`) file or other point cloud format that probably has some color information in it!

Thanks!